# How to measure distance on linear polar transformed data using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, transform, polar-coordinates

I am working on some image data that I am doing a polar transform on where I want to measure the width of bright rings in a circular type object.

Example image:

[image]

So far I have something like this using faux data:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('testimg.tif')
img_gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#threshold image to calculate center of object
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gry,254,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
M = cv2.moments(thresh)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

#convert white space around object to 0 intensity
img_gry[img_gry == 255] = 0

#calculate radius of image to be used for polar transform
radius = np.sqrt(((img_gry.shape[0]/2.0)**2.0)+((img_gry.shape[1]/2.0)**2.0))

#transform using center coordinates and radius
polar_image = cv2.linearPolar(img_gry,(cX, cY), radius, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
polar_image = polar_image.astype(np.uint8)

#add gaussian smoothing
polar_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(polar_image,(3,3),0)
```

This transform looks something like this:

[image]

And I will be looking at slices of the data that show intensity, like such:

[image]

My question from here is what formula to use to calculate the width of the bright peaks in the image. I don't really know what type of axes are used for displaying this transformation, which underlies my problem. For example, my non-transformed peaks have a width of ~3px, but the transformed data has a peak width of 8 units (radians? no clue). I'm wondering how exactly I can estimate the actual width of my non-transformed data based off the "distance" in this polar transformed data.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to compute in non-polar space?  Clearly, it would be very easy to identify and measure the peaks in that slice.  Changing to polar doesn't change the width of the signal spike in physical terms.  It just changes the representation.

Comment: I agree it would be easier to compute directly, but then how would you go about measuring pixel intensity at different thetas around the center? I was kind of stuck going between the two ideas, and I couldn't think of something to cleanly measure 360 degrees around the center to the edge of the spheroid. Perhaps I'm overthinking it.

Comment: Please show your original image before the polar transform. Once you find the peaks, you have both radius and angle, so you can compute the x,y locations from that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system Then just get the difference in cartesian coordinates as distance from the Pythagorean theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: If you think about how the polar transition is done, each radius line exactly corresponds to one scanline from your rectangular array.  So, you can search for peaks using the rectangular scanlines, just like your second plot above.  You could even compute rather easily which theta radius the scanline would map to.

Comment: I have added the original image. And forgive me if I am wrong, but I am not sure that the returned transformed data gives me radius and angle. It returns an array that is the same dimensions as my original image. For example, if I have a 100x100px image it returns a 100x100 array; this case happens to be around 300x300. From calculating using the distance formula of say r=3 and r=13 for peak width (obtained from the first peak in my representative slice above) and angle theta=270, which is the slice I took it from, I get a distance of 10px.